# HTML Unwanted padding at the bottom

Tags: html

I have created a page and just cannot get rid of the additional space that is being added at the bottom of the text. This creates a vertical scroll and white space that I don't want. The page needs to fit pixel for pixel.

[image: Space below the text, creating a vertical scroll bar and white space below]

I have tried various solutions from stackoverflow and the internet, but nothing takes away the space.

```
<body>
<div style="line-height: 20%; position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 728px; width: 100px;">
<span id="current_weather" style="letter-spacing: -0.1em; font-size:53px;"></span><span style="letter-spacing: -0.1em; font-size:53px;">&deg;C</span>
</div>  
</body>
```

My apologies if I have not posted the question in the right format

Comment: try bottom: 0 on parent div. I think it will help you

Comment: could you share complete code on fiddle or snippet

Comment: Upaded jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m0qLrk50/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this in your CSS:

```
*,html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

also, if you post a code snippet, or a jsFiddle, it would be easier for us to help you out. Consider doing so and I will take a look and help you achieve your goal. Hope this helps!

**EDIT - update with jsFiddle**

Here is the fixed version:

https://jsfiddle.net/m0qLrk50/8/

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3754712 if you provide me with a jsFiddle I will give it a look and post my answer if I find any. Thanks!

Comment: @user3754712 I am sorry but I don't see any padding problem, as there is a random `C` floating in the middle of the screen. I cannot help you if you don't provide me with the exact issue. Thanks

Comment: @Ivanov, I am trying to figure out how to link the image in jsfiddle

Comment: @user3754712 use imgur to post the image there and just copy the link over (right click View Image after upload and copy the link)Hope this helps!

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle. I have had to remove the WU_API_KEY and the real background image, as it is sensitive. The °C is the weather displayed without the weather and where it actually appears on the display.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150793/discussion-between-user3754712-and-n-ivanov).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add some resets to your stylesheet. For example:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address,
big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl,
dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside,
canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, 
nav, section { display: block; }
body { line-height: 1; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
} 

body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }

*, :before, :after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If that doesn't work, please share the whole code

Comment: Tried this, and it does not make a difference.